# Calcular quantos NaN em cada horário Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Boa dia,tenho um `DF` onde possui `NaN` e preciso contar quantos NaN tenho em cada horário.
Meu df tem um período de 31 dias.
Acredito que devo usar Groupby, porém não estou achando uma forma.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_hdf('./dados.hd5')

df.head()

Year_DoY_Hour          Temperatura
2016-01-01 00:00:00    NaN
2016-01-01 01:00:00    22.445700
2016-01-01 02:00:00    22.388300
2016-01-01 03:00:00    22.400000
2016-01-01 04:00:00    NaN
2016-01-01 05:00:00    22.133900
2016-01-01 06:00:00    21.948999
2016-01-01 07:00:00    21.787901
2016-01-01 08:00:00    21.610300
2016-01-01 09:00:00    NaN
.
.
.
2016-31-01 00:00:00    NaN
2016-31-01 01:00:00    21.310800
2016-31-01 02:00:00    22.910700
2016-31-01 03:00:00    23.810600
2016-31-01 04:00:00    NaN
```

Podemos ver que no horário `00:00:00` temos 2 `NaN` e no `03:00:00` temos 1 `NaN` e no `04:00:00` temos 2 `NaN`

Comment: Podes colocar o ficheiro em algum lado que se possa fazer download e testar?. Não estou familiarizado com hd5 mas acho que te consigo ajudar com o groupBy

Comment: Pode ser .csv, isso não tem problema. O problema é eu aplicar isso no df.

Comment: Ok vou fazer com csv a ver se te consigo ajudar

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A resposta que você tem está correta, mas não usa o Pandas (que foi o que você utiliza e perguntou). Eis uma que usa o Pandas então. :)

Basicamente a ideia é fazer o agrupamento definindo rótulos que usem a data (ano, mês e dia) e **apenas a hora**. O resto (minutos e segundos) você ignora. Dessa forma, cada agrupamento terá todas as entradas da mesma hora, e então é só contar o número de nulos (`NaN`). Uma questão importante é que a função de agrupamento espera uma função (ou lambda, como no caso do exemplo) que vai receber o índice da tabela. Logo, faz sentido converter a coluna de data/hora para `DateTime` primeiramente, e então transformá-la no índice da tabela. Assim você pode processar esse valor diretamente na função/lambda.

Eis um exemplo de código (documentado passo-a-passo):

```
import pandas as pd

# Somente para a leitura dos dados de teste
df = pd.read_csv('teste.csv', sep=',')

# Converte os dados da coluna data/hora para o formato DateTime
df['Year_DoY_Hour'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year_DoY_Hour'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S')

# Converte a coluna da data/hora para o índice da tabela
df = df.set_index('Year_DoY_Hour')

# Imprime os dados originais
print('Original:')
print('-' * 40)
print(df)

# Agrupa os dados pelo índice em rótulos do tipo "ano-dia-mês hora:00:00"
grouped = df.groupby(
                     lambda index: '{:04d}-{:02d}-{:02d} {:02d}:00:00' \
                     .format(index.year, index.day, index.month, index.hour)
                    )

# Faz a contagem para cada agrupamento e imprime
print('\n')
print('Contagem de NaNs por hora:')
print('-' * 40)
for label, group in grouped:
    # Conta o número de NaNs (nulos) na coluna `Temperatura` do grupo atual
    numNaNs = len(group[group['Temperatura'].isnull()])
    # Imprime a contagem do grupo (com o respectivo rótulo)
    print('{}: {}'.format(label, numNaNs))
```

Usando como dados de entrada um CSV com:

```
Year_DoY_Hour,Temperatura
2016-01-01 00:00:00,NaN
2016-01-01 00:01:00,NaN
2016-01-01 00:18:22,22.388300
2016-01-01 00:55:00,NaN
2016-01-01 01:00:00,22.445700
2016-01-01 02:00:00,22.388300
2016-01-01 03:00:00,22.400000
2016-01-01 04:00:00,NaN
2016-01-01 05:00:00,22.133900
2016-01-01 06:00:00,21.948999
2016-01-01 07:00:00,21.787901
2016-01-01 08:00:00,21.610300
2016-01-01 09:00:00,NaN
2016-01-01 09:07:18,NaN
2016-01-01 09:44:00,21.310800
2016-31-01 02:00:00,22.910700
2016-31-01 03:00:00,23.810600
2016-31-01 04:00:00,NaN
```

O resultado é:

```
Original:
----------------------------------------
                     Temperatura
Year_DoY_Hour
2016-01-01 00:00:00          NaN
2016-01-01 00:01:00          NaN
2016-01-01 00:18:22    22.388300
2016-01-01 00:55:00          NaN
2016-01-01 01:00:00    22.445700
2016-01-01 02:00:00    22.388300
2016-01-01 03:00:00    22.400000
2016-01-01 04:00:00          NaN
2016-01-01 05:00:00    22.133900
2016-01-01 06:00:00    21.948999
2016-01-01 07:00:00    21.787901
2016-01-01 08:00:00    21.610300
2016-01-01 09:00:00          NaN
2016-01-01 09:07:18          NaN
2016-01-01 09:44:00    21.310800
2016-01-31 02:00:00    22.910700
2016-01-31 03:00:00    23.810600
2016-01-31 04:00:00          NaN


Contagem de NaNs por hora:
----------------------------------------
2016-01-01 00:00:00: 3
2016-01-01 01:00:00: 0
2016-01-01 02:00:00: 0
2016-01-01 03:00:00: 0
2016-01-01 04:00:00: 1
2016-01-01 05:00:00: 0
2016-01-01 06:00:00: 0
2016-01-01 07:00:00: 0
2016-01-01 08:00:00: 0
2016-01-01 09:00:00: 2
2016-31-01 02:00:00: 0
2016-31-01 03:00:00: 0
2016-31-01 04:00:00: 1
```

Comment: É verdade Luiz, realmente seria mais apropriado com pandas, mas não tenho a sua experiência nesse modulo

Comment: @Miguel Não tem problema. A sua solução também é bacana e serve de referência/alternativa. :)

Comment: Uma pergunta Luiz, onde define que é só por hora/min/sec que quer agrupar, e não por ano/dia/mês também?

Comment: @Miguel Na função lambda utilizada para fazer o agrupamento. Ela recebe o índice de cada linha da tabela, e retorna um rótulo (label) único indicando o agrupamento. Como o índice é um `DateTime`, ela define o rótulo como `'{:04d}-{:02d}-{:02d} {:02d}:00:00'.format(index.year, index.day, index.month, index.hour)` (note o ":00:00" ali no final, para ignorar minutos e segundos - não era necessário, mas assim vai também pro rótulo final). Desse modo não somente a hora é considerada individualmente, mas em diferentes dias/meses/anos também. :)

Comment: Sim, obrigado Luiz eu depois testei isso e consegui perceber que não era feito o agrupamento só por hora. Obrigado

Answer (score 2):

Não sei bem como é o formato na realidade de hd5 (pesquisei mas não consegui perceber), se for tal e qual como o que puseste em vez de fazeres `...split(',')` como faço nos exemplos abaixo faz `....split('    ')` (4 espaços). Formato do csv que usei para testes é:

```
2016-01-01 00:00:00,    NaN
2016-01-01 01:00:00,    22.445700
2016-01-01 02:00:00,    22.388300
2016-01-01 03:00:00,    22.400000
2016-01-01 04:00:00,    NaN
2016-01-01 05:00:00,    22.133900
2016-01-01 06:00:00,    21.948999
2016-01-01 07:00:00,    21.787901
...
```

Com groupby podes fazer assim:

```
from itertools import groupby

with open('tests.csv', 'r') as f:
    dados = [(l.split(',')[0], l.split(',')[1].strip()) for l in f]
print(dados) # [('2016-01-01 00:00:00', 'NaN'), ('2016-01-01 01:00:00', '22.445700'), ('2016-01-01 02:00:00', '22.388300'), ('2016-01-01 03:00:00', '22.400000'), ...]
dados_sort = sorted((k.split()[1], v) for k, v in dados) # importante
for hora, group in groupby(dados_sort, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    group = list(group)
    if any(v == 'NaN' for k, v in group):
        print('Existem {} NaN na hora {}'.format(len(group), hora))
```

Output do programa para os dados que deste:

> Existem 2 NaN na hora 00:00:00
> Existem 2 NaN na hora 04:00:00
> Existem
>   1 NaN na hora 09:00:00

Mas sinceramente eu não faria assim neste caso (a não ser que fosse mesmo preciso), faria assim:

```
from collections import Counter

dados = {}
with open('tests.csv', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        hora, val = l.split(',') # hora e temperatura, deves ja ter isto devidido por linha no teu caso
        dados.setdefault(val.strip(), []).append(hora.split(' ')[1])
print(dados) # {'22.388300': ['02:00:00'], '23.810600': ['03:00:00'], '21.610300': ['08:00:00'], '22.400000': ['03:00:00'], '21.948999': ['06:00:00'], 'NaN': ['00:00:00', '04:00:00', '09:00:00', '00:00:00', '04:00:00'], '22.910700': ['02:00:00'], '22.445700': ['01:00:00'], '21.787901': ['07:00:00'], '22.133900': ['05:00:00'], '21.310800': ['01:00:00']}
print(Counter(dados['NaN']))
```

> {'00:00:00': 2, '04:00:00': 2, '09:00:00': 1}

Ou, se não precisares armazenar os valores todos podes só:

```
from collections import Counter

list_NaN = []
with open('tests.csv', 'r') as f:
    for l in f:
        hora, val = l.split(',')
        if val.strip() == 'NaN':
            list_NaN.append(hora.split(' ')[1])
print(Counter(list_NaN))
```

> {'00:00:00': 2, '04:00:00': 2, '09:00:00': 1}